# How to exclude character that has preceding character different than specified in regular expression?

Tags: regex

With regular expression I would like to get all characters between round brackets, but `\(` and `\)` characters should be also included in the result.

Examples:

```
input: fo(ob)a)r
output: ob

input: foo(bar\(qwerty\))baz
output: bar\(qwerty\)
```

This is what I used for finding text between brackets:
`(?<=\()([^\s\(\)]+)(?=\))`, but I can't make exceptions for brackets preceded by `\`.

Comment: What would `f(o(ob)a)r` output ?

Comment: It would output `ob`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this :

```
.*(?<!\\)\((.*?)(?<!\\)\)
```

Basically, it matches as many characters as possible until it sees an open parenthesis without a backslash (using a negative lookbehind), then groups the next matching characters until a closing parenthesis (still without a backslash).

Note that this regex may not work properly if you escape the backslashes.

Example : https://regex101.com/r/BqVKZp/1

Answer (score 0):

This regex works for both your examples, without any lookaheads and lookbehinds:

`\((.+[^\\])\)`

A `U` flag is needed.

Comment: This regex on `f(o(ob)a)r` would output `(o(ob)a)`

Comment: Oh, it's not in the original question, now I see the comment though. Let me think about it :)